# Uploading and Playing large videos. HttpRuntime tag settings Combination. Asp.net4.0 , C#

Tags: web-config, httpruntime, request-timed-out

net page to upload a large file and a generic handler to play these large wmv video files of size which can be upto 150 MB's. I have the file content stored in varbinary type in SQL Server 2005.
I have set following settings in httpRuntime in web.config

```
<httpRuntime executionTimeout="110" 
                 maxRequestLength="2097151"
                 requestLengthDiskThreshold="2097150"
                 shutdownTimeout="600"
                 delayNotificationTimeout="400"/>
```

The problem is that sometimes my files doesnt play. It get uploaded properly but when playing the request seems to get timeout. I was able to play files upto 100 MB's. It works 9 out of 10 times on local and production but why does it fails sometimes. The same file get played in one instance but on other instance it doesnt. Can anybody suggest where the problem may be. I think there must be some combination of httpRuntime attributes which i am missing. Please suggest. Its a production issue which keeps popping up.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use IHttpHandler? try this [Uploading FIle Using IHttpHandler](http://mikehadlow.blogspot.com/2008/02/restful-file-uploads-with.html) Might be there will be better solutions to use IHttpHandler if you will search for it.

Comment: i have already used Ihttphandler for uploading and downloading files. httpRuntime settings in web.config are still required for it.